# Node JS: Data is not reaching next .then()

Tags: node.js

I am not able to change the status from o to 1. The server is returning 500 . I don't know what is wrong I have done everything fine why its not pushing.

```
function changeAdminStatus(req, res, next){
getSuperAminById(req.params.id)
    .then(function(data){
      if(data.account.status == 1)
          {
              console.log(data);
              Admin.findByIdAndUpdate(data._id,  {
                $push: {
                    'account.status' : 0
                }
            }, function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    res.sendStatus(500);
                }
                 else if(doc) res.sendStatus(200);
                      else res.sendStatus(200);
            }
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in second line use return will take the result to the next .then

```
function changeAdminStatus(req, res, next){
return  getSuperAminById(req.params.id)
 .then(function(data){
   if(data.account.status == 1)
      {
          console.log(data);
          Admin.findByIdAndUpdate(data._id,  {
            $push: {
                'account.status' : 0
            }
        }, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }
             else if(doc) res.sendStatus(200);
                  else res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: no rahul I guess return is required when your function is inside .then(function(){)

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting MongoDB like that

```
        $push: {
                'account.status' : 0
            }
```

instead

```
         $push: {
                'account'  :{  'status' : 0 }
            }
```

Comment: "account" : {
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2015-12-30T10:33:48.448Z"),
        "uuid" : "cfa82a00-aee0-11e5-9ccf-a150cf7aac16",
        "status" : 1
    },

Comment: my schema looks like this

Comment: In Admin.findByIdAndUpdate ,Admin is a mangoose model ? and the schema are correct ?

Comment: The above is the model schema or query? if its a model schema don't use ISODate ,As far i know query only will accept ISODate

Comment: Yes Admin is the model and account is a part of my schema .

Comment: that ISO comes from the function Date.now() I guess

Comment: Then you have to pass query like $push: {'account'  :{  'status' : 0 }},becuase mongodb query will not work as like javascript ,As far i know only MongoDB will accept ISODate ,Its not a function under javascript ,Might be ISODate internally using Date.now() ,just an information :)

Comment: account: {
        status: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        uuid: { type: String, default: uuid.v1() },
        createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
   },   this is how i defined the date and status is not changing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99399/discussion-between-krishnakumar-sekar-and-sac-dahal).